# Заменить все символы в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Добрый вечер.

Каким образом в javascript можно заменить все символы на нужные мне?
Я вытягиваю альбомы из фейсбука, и он позволяет в названии альбома писать **"** и **'**. Естественно у меня на сайте это выливается в проблему.
Вот что я пытался:

```
function clearFromSlashes(str){
    var slashes1="\'";   //заменяем одинарные кавычки
    var slashes2="\"";    //заменяем двойные кавычки
    var newStr=str.replace(slashes1," ");
    return newStr.replace(slashes2," ");
}
```

Эта функция заменяет только самые первые кавычки, если дальше в названии кавычки встречаются еще раз, функция их пропускает. **Как их отловить тоже?** И.. как вы видите я сделал 2 переменные slashes1 и slashes1, почему-то если писал вот так:

```
var slashes1="\',\"";   - оно не работало.. не знаю почему
```

Comment: походу нужно через do while крутить, но как узнать сколько в тексте одинародных или двойных кавычек?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

replace использует регулярное выражение, а не строку.

```
str.replace(/'|"/g,'')
```

Comment: ага, спасибо буду знать, ато я уже такой велик успел построить))
  
    var slashes1="\'";
 var slashes2="\"";

 var one=str.split(slashes1).length-1;
 var two=str.split(slashes2).length-1;

 do{
  str=str.replace(slashes1,"");
  one--;
 }while(one>0)

 do{
  str=str.replace(slashes2,"");
  two--;
 }while(two>0)

Answer (score 3):

Как минимум дедовский способ:

```
function htmlQuotes(str) {
  var replace = [
    '\'': '&quot;',
    '\"': '&quot;',
    '<' : '&lt;',
    '>' : '&gt;' // и так далее
  ];
  for (var n in replace)
    str = str.split(n).join(replace[n]);
  return str;
}
```